# Why are html and php files not properly exchanging information?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a website where a user logs in, enters information that is submitted to a database, and then can call information from the database that will be inserted into an html text element. I have separate html files for each website page, and multiple php files. They are all contained and linked properly on the same server, under the same FTP account. ***EDIT: THIS WAS MY PROBLEM. I HAD SEPARATE PHP AND HTML FILES. ONCE I COMBINED THEM, I NO LONGER NEEDED THE JAVASCRIPT AND EVERYTHING WORKED FINE.*** My code has been checked by multiple sources, and I can have the user correctly input information into the database. When it comes to retrieving the information to be displayed on client-side, however, the php will not change the html via javascript.

I am currently using 000webhost.com, but I tried plugging the files into dreamweaver and the files still aren't communicating properly. I'm wondering whether this is a software limitation (aka something is going wrong with 000webhost.com) or if there is a key piece of info I am missing, such as a command that will link the files together.

Here is the example php and html for one of the retrieve information functions:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$database = "-";
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$link) {
die(mysqli_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT UserClassName FROM UserInfo1 WHERE UserEmail = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['useremail']) . "'";

if (!$sql) {
die(mysqli_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result) {
die(mysqli_error());
}

?>
<script>
function getclassname() {
    return document.getElementById("UserClassName").innerHTML = "<?php echo 
$result ?>";
    }
</script>


<html>
<body onload="getclassname(); getcurrentlevel();">
<h1 class="text-center" id="UserClassName" name="UserClassName"><b>Welcome Enviroquest Research Team!</b></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why?? Why not just use PHP to write the result, instead of relying on javascript? Remember that PHP runs before the page is output to the browser, and javascript after. If you want to call a PHP function after it's already been sent to the browser, then use ajax to call a PHP script to get the information you want.

Comment: @aynber I tried Ajax, but was getting the same result and, admittedly, I am not fluent in Ajax. Doesn't it require much more complicated code?

Comment: @aynber I would also rather not parse and process json. If Ajax is simpler I would prefer to use that, but I can't find any example of ajax doing what I need and what the code would look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is that you put the javascript code outside the html. It should be placed before the closing body tag.

This is what your html should look like :

```
<?php // your php code here ?>
<html> 
  <body onload="getclassname(); getcurrentlevel();">
    <h1 class="text-center" id="UserClassName" name="UserClassName"><b>Welcome Enviroquest Research Team!</b></h1>

    <script>
      function getclassname() {
        document.getElementById("UserClassName").innerHTML = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
      }
      function getcurrentlevel() { 
        // this function should be remove if not used
      }
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The javascript code itself is actually in the php file. Should I change that?